# Are there nilpotent Manin Triples?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie bialgebra and denote by $\mathfrak{d}$ the double of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. $\mathfrak{d}$ is a Manin triple. Are there known examples or conditions on $\mathfrak{g}$ for which this double is nilpotent or results that this is impossible?

It is not enough to ask that both $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^*$ (with the induced Lie algebra structure) are nilpotent. A counterexample is given by the simplest non-abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = \langle x,y \rangle$ with bracket $[x,y] = x$. Giving $\mathfrak{g}^* = \langle x^*,y^* \rangle$ the bracket $[x^*,y^*] = x^*$ makes $\mathfrak{g}$ into anilpotent Lie bialgebra whose double is not nilpotent.

I am very grateful for any comments.

Comment: Beware, the non Abelian 2dimensional Lie algebra is solvable, but not nilpotent. Nice question anyway (both solvable and nilpotent versions)